# Want to scrape with Selenium but webpage thinks i am a robot

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

Want to scrape with Selenium but webpage (Cloudflare) thinks i am a robot.

I tried adding `options`, going headless, waiting until a specific `id` shows up, but the webpage just never fully loads.

How do you bypass this?

FYI just for an academic project not trying to do anything nefarious.

```
def get_reviews(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "carousel-module--container--27wzs")))
        sleep(3)

        response_text = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response_text, 'html.parser')
        udemy_body = soup.find('body', {'id': 'udemy'})

        if udemy_body:
            # Get the structure!
            # print(udemy_body.prettify())
            review_spans = udemy_body.find_all('span', class_='ud-text-md review--review-content-with-modal-trigger--vsRaS')
            reviews = [review_span.get_text(strip=True) for review_span in review_spans]
            print(reviews)
        else:
            logger.warning(f"Body element with id 'udemy' not found for {url}.")

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"An error occurred for {url}: {e}")

    finally:
        driver.quit()

udemy_course_url = 'https://www.udemy.com/course/deep-learning-tensorflow-2/'
get_reviews(udemy_course_url)
```

Options I'm testing with including:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")

options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36")

# options.add_argument("--headless")

options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")

options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
```

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: If the site set the threshold to the aggressive side, you're not going to be able to bypass Cloudflare's bot detection. That aside, search for forks of Selenium built for stealth.

Comment: @ewokx Added code above.

Comment: It thinks you are a robot because your code obviously IS a robot.  They're just trying to protect their copyrighted information.

Answer (score 1):

Udemy uses bot-detection software. Frameworks such as https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase can make bots appear human. SeleniumBase uses [UC Mode](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/help_docs/uc_mode.md) for that.

After `pip install seleniumbase`, run the following script with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(uc=True)
driver.get("https://www.udemy.com/course/deep-learning-tensorflow-2/")
driver.uc_click('button[data-purpose*="show-reviews"] span')

breakpoint()

driver.quit()
```

That script calls a `breakpoint()` to pause it on the reviews/ratings section for the Tensorflow Course. (Type `c` and press ENTER in the console to continue from the breakpoint when ready.)

Replace the `breakpoint()` with the rest of your script for getting the reviews.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you for providing an actually useful answer! Somehow it is still only able to load 4 out of 11 reviews for some reason, like the driver isnt capturing the new html after the button is clicked?

Comment: More reviews may appear after scrolling.